# how to add values from a different data frame pertaining to a same column with same values but in different position in python (check body)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the following two data frames:

TitleId, position and averageRating are columns

df1

```
TitleId: t1,t1,t2,t3,t4..
position: actor, director, director, director,director..
```

df2

```
TitleId: t1,t2,t3,t4..
averageRating: 5,4,3,2..
```

The number of rows also differ in these data frames. I want to add the average rating column to my df1 in a way that average rating of t1 should be in the same row wherever t1 appears in my data and so on. the output should be like this:

new_df1

```
TitleId: t1,t1,t2,t3,t4..
position: actor, director, director, director,director..
averageRating: 5,5,4,3,2..
```

I am working in Python.

Comment: (a) are you using pandas? (b) you say you want to add the average ratings column - but according to the desired output, it's a row and not a column. Could you please explain?

Comment: a) yes I am using Pandas, b) titleId, position and average rating all are columns..